# Pyspark add column converting existing javascript utc column to string

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark

I have a dataframe with a column storing utc (javascript timestamp, named utc) and I'm trying to add to it a column with the utc stored as a readable string.

```
from datetime import datetime
panel_json = panel_json.withColumn('timestamp', datetime.utcfromtimestamp(panel_json.utc/1000.0).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') )
```

But any attempt I do gives me

> TypeError: a float is required

I tried as well to put float around panel_json.utc

```
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(panel_json.utc)/1000.0).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') )
```

And several other tries with quotes, removing panel_json etc... but I'm not able to make it work. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Python library cannot be used that way. You can create UDF for that formatting or - which is much faster - let pyspark [date_format](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format) built-in udf do the job.

Comment: Sorry, but got lost there, is not possible to add a column based on a function on another column?

Comment: It is possible - using user defined functions (UDFs) in python or functions provided by spark (date_format in your case)